# Can Anyone tell me how can i solve this Exception

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

```
class Revers
{
    static void temp(String k)
    {

        int x;
        char ch[]= k.toCharArray(); //Convert String into character
        char p[]=k.toCharArray();    //Convert String into character
        x=k.length();
        System.out.println(x);

        for(int i=0;i<x;x--,i++) 
        {   
            p[i]=ch[x]; `/*Exception comes   here*/`      
            System.out.println(p[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... s)
    {

        String g="HEllo java";
        temp(g); //passig g as argument
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you decrementing **x** as well? Either remove it or try to handle it.

Comment: source: `p[i]=ch[x];` and `ch[x]` is out of bound since `x == ch.length`

Comment: Please no answers to this. There are alot of answers very much similar to this

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero-indexed.

Let's assume for the sake of argument that `k` is of length 10.  What would happen here?:

```
int x;
char ch[]= k.toCharArray(); //Convert String into character
char p[]=k.toCharArray();    //Convert String into character
x=k.length();
```

`ch` is now also of length 10, which means its indices range from 0-9.  And `x` is now also 10.  Then you do this:

```
p[i]=ch[x];
```

`i` is 0, so that's fine.  But `x` is 10.  `ch` only goes from 0-9.  Hence the error.  You want your upper-bound value to be *one less than* the length of the string:

```
x = k.length() - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
x=k.length();
```

And then tell me which element is accessed here:

```
p[i]=ch[x];
```

I'm sure you'll find out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`ch[x - 1]` is the change:

```
  int x;
        final char ch[] = k.toCharArray(); // Convert String into character
        final char p[] = k.toCharArray(); // Convert String into character
        x = k.length();
        System.out.println(x);

        for (int i = 0; i < x; x--, i++) {
            p[i] = ch[x - 1];
            System.out.println(p[i]);
        }
```

You are trying to get 'x' index from the array but there are x-1

Answer (score 0):

```
class Revers
{
static void temp(String k)
{

int x;
char ch[]= k.toCharArray(); //Convert String into character
char p[]=k.toCharArray();    //Convert String into character


x=k.length()-1;//Here is the correction*********************



System.out.println(x);

for(int i=0;i<x;x--,i++) 
{   
p[i]=ch[x]; /*Exception comes   here*/  
System.out.println(p[i]);
}
}
public static void main(String... s)
{

String g="HEllo java";
temp(g); //passig g as argument
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned `Array` index starts at `zero`

Your logic reverses only half the string, In order for your string to be completely reversed

```
for (int i = 0; i < k.length(); x--, i++) {
  p[i] = ch[x - 1];
}
```